# 3-Dimension List or Map

Tags: java, arrays, list, dictionary

I need something like a 3-dimension (like a list or a map), which I fill with 2 Strings and an Integer within a loop. But, unfortunately I don't know which data structure to use and how.

```
// something like a 3-dimensional myData
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myData.add("abc", "def", 123);
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the three values?

Comment: They come dynamically from JTextFields and JButtons.

Comment: Ok, but do you want to _do_ with them?

Comment: Not sure what is your exact use case so providing one more option. If you can depend upon an open source library then you can leverage [Guava's Table](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) class.

Comment: Then go with duffymo's answer, then insert them into the DB from the list when appropriate

Comment: You can use nested maps `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create an object that encapsulates the three together and add them to an array or List:

```
public class Foo {
    private String s1;
    private String s2; 
    private int v3;
    // ctors, getters, etc.
}

List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    foos.add(new Foo("abc", "def", 123);
}
```

If you want to insert into a database, write a DAO class:

```
public interface FooDao {
    void save(Foo foo);    
}
```

Implement as needed using JDBC.

Comment: I need a similar "container" class for storing exactly three properties. I initialize those properties through the constructor, and I need to have access to every property separately. The class has no any logic in it, just those three properties and a constructor. What is the best way to access those properties? Is in this case setting the properties as public okay, or I should write getters? The properties are final.

Comment: Okay?  Who will stop you?  Make them public final; they are immutable that way. Expect the OO police to come knocking.

Comment: I am asking if it's okay because I do not want to code something that is against the OO concepts. From your answer I assume that final properties are not requiring getters, as they cannot be changed anyway? Or is "final public" okay only in case of this small case?

Comment: "Against OO concepts"?  There are no OO police.  You can do whatever you wish.  You should think about and understand the implications.  You don't need permission.  This is code.  If it doesn't work, change it.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 15):

A Google's [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) code would look like this:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Table;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable;

Table<String, String, Integer> table = HashBasedTable.create();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    table.put("abc", "def", i);
}
```

Code above will construct a HashMap inside a HashMap with a constructor that looks like this:

```
Table<String, String, Integer> table = Tables.newCustomTable(
        Maps.<String, Map<String, Integer>>newHashMap(),
        new Supplier<Map<String, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> get() {
        return Maps.newHashMap();
    }
});
```

In case you want to override the underlying structures you can easily change it.

Answer (score 5):

Simply create a class

```
 class Data{
  String first;
  String second;
  int number;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what the relationship between the values are.

1) you just want to store all three in the same order as they come: create a custom class that encompasses all three elements and add an instance of this class to a `List<MyData>`.

2) you want to associate the sirst string with the second-and-third data (and associate the second with the int): create a Map> and add the elements to it (you will have to create the inner map for each new first string)

3) you don't want to keep duplicates, but you don't want/need a map.: Create a custom type (a'la 1)) and put them in a `Set<MyData>`

3) mix-and match

Answer (score 1):

For synchronized structure, you can use Tables.synchronizedTable from [guava 22](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#synchronizedTable-com.google.common.collect.Table-) or later.

```
Table<String, String, Integer> table = Tables.synchronizedTable(HashBasedTable.<String, String, Integer>create());
```

To add an element into the collection you can do:

```
table.put("abc", "def", 123);
```

To remove the element from the collection:

```
table.remove("abc", "def");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to create a class:

```
Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> myData;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go with this code!

```
public class List3D {

    public static class MyList {
        String a = null;
        String b = null;
        String c = null;

        MyList(String a, String b, String c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<MyList> myLists = new ArrayList<>();
        myLists.add(new MyList("anshul0", "is", "good"));
        myLists.add(new MyList("anshul1", "is", "good"));
        myLists.add(new MyList("anshul2", "is", "good"));
        myLists.add(new MyList("anshul3", "is", "good"));
        myLists.add(new MyList("anshul4", "is", "good"));
        myLists.add(new MyList("anshul5", "is", "good"));

        for (MyList myLista : myLists)
            System.out.println(myLista.a + myLista.b + myLista.c);
    }
}
```