# Java, map 3 items

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I need a structure to translate different enumerators (Integers) from one API to another one. The APIs are GL, DX9 and DX10.
The integers are not contiguous, that is we don't have all the values from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>

Example:

Given [GL, DX9, DX10]

one entry could be:

[`COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT`, `D3DFMT_DXT1`, `DXGI_FORMAT_BC1_UNORM`]

That is:

[33776, 827611204, 71]

I should be able to get every API enum from any other one. This means, for example, I have `COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT` and I want the DX10 equivalent or I have `D3DFMT_DXT1` and I want the GL equivalent and so on..

I saw some option, like attaching different subkeys [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148331/how-to-get-a-hashmap-value-with-three-values) or concatenating all of them in Strings like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400285/3-dimension-list-or-map), but they don't look very practical/elegant to me, is there a better option?

Comment: You could just have 6 maps: GL to DX9, GL to DX10, DX9 to GL etc. But I don't think it's a good idea to do that. Some enums just don't have equivalents in the other APIs, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I also wouldn't like to have 6 maps.. I'd use `GL_NONE` and other dx equivalents, I'd like to achieve something [similar](https://code.google.com/p/rotoglup-scratchpad/source/browse/trunk/misc/?r=18)

Comment: I would create a single enumerant, each value would contain the GL value and their potential equivalents in DX9 and DX10, each value would have a name that would make sense for the three ones.